# iOS app download flickr photos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, flickr

I am developing an app for a school. They keep their photos on flickr. They want a photo gallery page in their app that will pull the photos from their flickr page. I was wondering what the simplest way to download photos from flickr is considering:
1. I don't want to upload any photos.
2. I don't want the user to have to log in.
3. I can't supply the url for individual photos since the school will presumably update their flickr more often than I can update the app. I just want the app to pull all of the photos, in their albums.

Thanks so much,
Luke

Comment: check this flicker example in Swift https://github.com/hadanischal/FlickrSearchExample

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
-(void)getUserID{

    NSString *methodName = @"flickr.people.findByUsername";

    NSString *userName = @"<Your_Username>";

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?method=%@&api_key=%@",kFlickrAPIURL,methodName,kFlickrAPIKey];
urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&username=%@&format=%@&nojsoncallback=1", urlString,userName,kFlickrResponseFormat];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    userIDRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:userIDRequest delegate:self];
    [connection release];
}

-(void)getUserPhotos:(NSString *)userID{

    NSString *methodName = @"flickr.people.getPhotos";

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?method=%@&key=%@",kFlickrAPIURL,methodName,kFlickrAPIKey];    

    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&user_id=%@&format=%@&nojsoncallback=1",urlString,userID,kFlickrResponseFormat];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    imagesRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:imagesRequest delegate:self];
    [connection release];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
    if (userIDRequest == connection.originalRequest)
    {
        NSString *userId = [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"user"] objectForKey:@"id"];
        if (userId != nil)
            [self getUserPhotos:userId];
    } else if (imagesRequest == connection.originalRequest) {

        NSArray *photos = [[jsonDic objectForKey:@"photos"] objectForKey:@"photo"];

        for (NSDictionary *photo in photos)
        {
            // Get title of the image
            NSString *title = [photo objectForKey:@"title"];

            // Build the URL to where the image is stored (see the Flickr API)
            // In the format http://farmX.static.flickr.com/server/id/secret
            // Notice the "_s" which requests a "small" image 75 x 75 pixels
            NSString *photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com", [photo objectForKey:@"farm"]];
            photoURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@_%@_s.jpg", photoURLString, [photo objectForKey:@"server"], [photo objectForKey:@"id"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];

        }
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Download [ObjectiveFlickr](https://github.com/lukhnos/objectiveflickr/) and there is a sample "RandomPublicPhoto" in examples folder